# Можно ли создать обработчик событий при слайдинге на Android?

Tags: java, android, sliding

Есть приложение с базой данных, хочу сделать так чтобы при перелистывании влево происходили одни действия, а вправо - другие. Например, у меня есть таблица в БД - "сотрудники" (ФИО и номер телефона). Я беру данные из БД и вывожу их на экран. Изначально я вижу только ФИО, листаю вправо и вижу следующее ФИО, а если на каком-то ФИО листаю влево, то вижу ФИО и номер телефона этого человека. Если бы можно было сделать такой функционал с помощью кнопок, проблем бы не было. Но нужно сделать именно слайдинг. Вообще такое возможно сделать? Прочитал о слайдинге несколько статей из Интернета, но ответа не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите ViewPager. У него есть три метода которые отслеживают слайдинг

```
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
      int positionOffsetPixels) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
  }
});
```

Comment: А как тогда отследить влево пролистали или вправо?

Comment: Смотреть как меняется номер слайда

Answer (score 0):

Создаете активити Ставите на него `View Pager` который будет отображать фрагмент и при слайдинге  (Повесьте на него костюм так как в стандарт виде он вам не подойдет ) иполучайте значения , а в адаптаре поставте динамическое заполнение Тоого или иного фрагмента